# regex for any alphanumeric characters except the number 0

Tags: php, regex

For non-zero I have `/^[1-9][0-9]*$/`, and for alphanumeric `^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$`, but I don't know how to combine these.

Please help with regex for any alphanumeric pattern except a single 0

Answer (score 3):

You can use this pattern to prevent matches starting with `0`

```
^(?!0)[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$
```

If `01` is ok but not just `0` use this pattern

```
^(?!0$)[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

here what you need :

```
/^[1-9a-zA-Z ]+$/
```

Explaination :Allow numbers from 1 to 9, char from A to Z (non sensitive case) and space allowed.

Comment: seems like OP wants '90' but not '0' by itself

Comment: I am sorry, I did some testing and I am getting false for negative numbers, and for false. In other words, a patterns like 0, -2, or false are not matched. How could I do to get no match only for single digit 0 (zero) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Without lookahead you can use:

```
^[1-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z ]*$
```

Of course with lookahead it is shorter:

```
^(?!0$)[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$
```

Comment: You can append `space` pattern

Comment: Do you mean to match spaces also?

Comment: OP pattern `[0-9a-zA-Z ]`

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that, included it now.

Answer (score 0):

There are many good answers to this question.

But considering the OP's question, I believe the best way to do this would be:

`(^[1-9a-zA-Z ]$|^[1-9a-zA-Z ][0-9a-zA-Z ]+$)`

- `^[1-9a-zA-Z ]$` if there is only one character
- `^[1-9a-zA-Z ][0-9a-zA-Z ]+$` if more than one character.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, none of these worked and I had to read manual and come up with the one that worked. I was aided by the answers posted by others.

```
([^0]|[0-9a-zA-Z_ ]{2,}&)
```

if one character, not a single zero. If more than one character, number, letter, underscore and space are a go.

Tested as follows:

```
$string0 = 0;
$string1 = 1;
$string2 = 9;
$string3 = '1 - 3 Million'; // is telling this is zero
$string4 = 'false';
$string5 = '0 - 3 Million';
$string6 = '011';
$regex = '([^0]|[0-9a-zA-Z_ ]{2,}&)';
$modifiers = '';
$exp = chr(1) . $regex . chr(1) . $modifiers;
$expresion = $exp;
echo 'CHR(1):'.chr(1).' END';
echo '<br/>';
echo 'EXPRESSION 1:'.$exp.' END';
echo '<br/>';
echo 'Is this non-zero? '.preg_match($expresion, $string0);
echo '<br/>';
echo 'Is this non-zero? '.preg_match($expresion, $string1);
echo '<br/>';
echo 'Is this non-zero? '.preg_match($expresion, $string2);
echo '<br/>';
echo 'Is this non-zero? '.preg_match($expresion, $string3);
echo '<br/>';
echo 'Is this non-zero? '.preg_match($expresion, $string4);
echo '<br/>';
echo 'Is this non-zero? '.preg_match($expresion, $string5);
echo '<br/>';
echo 'Is this non-zero? '.preg_match($expresion, $string6);
```

OUTPUT

```
EXPRESSION 1:([^0]|[0-9a-zA-Z_ ]{2,}&) END
Is this non-zero? 0
Is this non-zero? 1
Is this non-zero? 1
Is this non-zero? 1
Is this non-zero? 1
Is this non-zero? 1
Is this non-zero? 1
```